# Check if my coordinate points are inside a polygon drawn by a user in leaflet R

Tags: r, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I want to check if my coordinate points are inside a polygon that is drawn by a user in leaflet.

For that, i have one file with my points : shp_geo_sirene

```
> shp_geo_sirene

Simple feature collection with 103600 features and 0 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 47.067916 ymin: -3.659252 xmax: 48.866675 ymax: 4.774807
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
First 5 features:
                     geometry
1  POINT (48.326389 -2.882054)
2  POINT (48.306272 -2.867231)
3  POINT (48.310791 -2.87197)
4  POINT (48.296586 -2.872507)
5  POINT (48.319363 -2.907008)
```

And another file that i catch and transform a polygon drawn by the user

```
# catch a polygon drawn by the user
my_draw_coordinates <- input$leaflet_geonosis_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates

# transfom in data.table
df_poly <- data.table(
    pts = sort(rep(c(1:(length(unlist(my_draw_coordinates))/2)),2)),
    cds_gps = unlist(my_draw_coordinates))
df_poly <- copy(dcast.data.table(df_poly, pts~type, value.var="cds_gps"))
      
# transform in st format
shp_poly <- df_poly[, list(lat,lon)] %>%
    as.data.frame %>%
    st_as_sf(coords = c(1,2)) %>%
    st_set_crs(4326)
```

```
> shp_poly

Simple feature collection with 5 features and 0 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 48.489989 ymin: -2.799787 xmax: 48.526382 ymax: -2.717045
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
                     geometry
1 POINT (48.526382 -2.793607)
2 POINT (48.515467 -2.717045)
3 POINT (48.489989 -2.725285)
4 POINT (48.492947 -2.799787)
5 POINT (48.526382 -2.793607)
```

Finaly i use st_intersects, in order to check if my points [shp_geo_sirene] are inside the polygon [shp_poly ]

```
# intersects siren x geometry
      bin_sirene_in_poly <- st_intersects(
        shp_geo_sirene,
        shp_poly,
        sparse = FALSE)
```

But it's not working, the result is every time outside the polygon.
Could you please help me or give me directions regarding this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a solution :

it's necessary to put a polygon geometry for my shp_poly object :

```
# my_draw_coordinates
my_draw_coordinates <- input$leaflet_geonosis_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates
     
# df polygon draw
lon = unlist(my_draw_coordinates)[seq(1,length(unlist(my_draw_coordinates)), 2)]
lat = unlist(my_draw_coordinates)[seq(2,length(unlist(my_draw_coordinates)), 2)]
shp_poly <- list(structure(c(lon,lat), .Dim = c(length(lon), 2L))) %>%
   st_polygon()
```